# sql extract month and assigned semester to them

Tags: sql, oracle, extract

I have some data of date in one column, I want to add one new column as semester:

Jan-Apr is Spring

May-Aug is Summer

Sep-Dec is Fall

```
 start date
--------------
'12-JAN-2019'
'28-DEC-2018'
'05-JAN-2019'
'10-JULY-2018'
```

So I tried:

```
select id, case(
   when extract(month from start_date) between 1 and 4 then 'Spring'
   when extract(month from start_date) between 5 and 8 then 'Summer'
   else 'Fall'
   end)
from table
```

But oracle shows error: missing right parenthesis
Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Remove the parenthesis after `case` and `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT id,
       CASE
         WHEN Extract(month FROM start_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN 'Spring'
         WHEN Extract(month FROM start_date) BETWEEN 5 AND 8 THEN 'Summer'
         ELSE 'Fall'
       END AS Semester
FROM   tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, (case
   when extract(month from start_date) between 1 and 4 then 'Spring'
   when extract(month from start_date) between 5 and 8 then 'Summer'
   else 'Fall'
   end)
from table
```

Comment: This is just the code from the OP and therefore hardly an answer. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @stickybit . . . The parentheses have been moved to fix the syntax error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Ah now I see. It's like one of these find the error in the other picture riddles... My fault, sorry, Mladen S.

Comment: @Mladen S - code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem (see comments above).